# Generating image thumbnails using php - without running out of memory

Tags: php, gd, image-resizing

I am currently using a php gd implementation to resize images which constantly runs out of memory - rather quickly. I guess the problem are the php functions, like imagecreatefromstring etc.

Is there an easy implementation to resizing images which doesn't use this functions, so I won't have to increase my php.ini memory limit?

Comment: Maybe there's a memory leak in your code, but who cares :) (Show us code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GD don't use that much memory, so you have other problems in your code.

If you resize multiple images and don't call `imagedestroy` on a newly created image, you run in memory leaks.

Comment: A true color image can use `width x height x 4 x <fudge factor>` bytes of memory. `createimagefromjpg` on a 5 mega pixel image and 20MB memory limit will immediately exhaust all memory.

Comment: I know, but the default memory limit in PHP5.3 is 128M, which surely fits. If your hoster don't support a suitable memory limit and wont change it for you, you should look for another hoster..

Answer (score 5):

here is a PHP function for you

```
 function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width,$desired_h) {

  /* read the source image */
  $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
  $width = imagesx($source_image);
  $height = imagesy($source_image);

  $desired_height = $desired_h;

  /* create a new, "virtual" image */
  $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

  /* copy source image at a resized size */
  imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

  /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
  imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);
}
```

Source : davidwalsh.name/create-image-thumbnail-php

Comment: Even though your version is very slightly different, you should really include credit to the source: https://davidwalsh.name/create-image-thumbnail-php

Comment: @Brett Well, You're right thou I don't really remember where did I get the code from before, I copied it from a project where I already use it, I'm not sure if the source you linked is the source anyway, maybe he got it from somewhere else too, and myabe I did. if I know the source I'd link it.