# Resizing image with PHP upload to SQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am using a pretty simple script to upload pictures to the database.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $album_id = $_POST['album'];
        $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $random_name = rand();

        if(empty($file)){
        ?>
            MUST BE JPG

        <?php } else {
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'uploads/'.$random_name.'.jpg');
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos VALUES('', '$name', '$album_id', '$random_name.jpg')");
        ?>

        UPLOADED
        <?php
    }
}
?>

<input type="file" name="file" id="imgInp" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload"  />
```

I am looking for a way to resize those images when they are being uploaded. I am not too sure what width I want, but what would be the easiest/best way to run such a code? I am been

Comment: You will need to use something like GD Library to resize the image. What have you tried?

Comment: I have been looking at a bunch of tutorials. I wasnt too sure where to start or what would actually do the trick. I was hoping for an easy way. Basically add something before the move_uploaded_file that will resize it. It doesnt look like its that easy.

Comment: You won't be able to do too much before you `move_uploaded_file`. Basically, once you have the file uploaded & moved, you can then resize it and write that to your filesystem. You can then save that path in your DB. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088666/generating-image-thumbnails-using-php-without-running-out-of-memory

Comment: Twisty, you are able to resize the photo using the temp path.  Using Imagick php class.  I do it all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running PHP 5.3 or greater, you will be able to use image magick which is built in.

Using the following code above your move_uploaded_file and it will resize it to 400 width and auto height.

```
        $image = new Imagick($file_tmp);
        $image->thumbnailImage(400, 0);
        $image->writeImage($newPath);
```

The first line creates an instance of the class Imagick, and passes in your file.

The second line creates the thumbnail, You can change the two numbers to whatever you like.

- The first number is width
- The second number is height

0 means auto, so by setting the first parameter to 400, and second to 0, this will maintain the aspect of the image.

The final line then writes the thumbnail to the directory of your choice.